# DIablo 3 install space and running diablo 3 plain from a diablo 3 RoS install

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I have scratched my copy of Diablo 3, and now the game skips.

I know that if I install the game from a valid disc, I will be able to use my scratched disc to validate the install, and play without the skipping.

Can I install Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls on my Xbox 360, and use the Diablo 3 disc to validate the Diablo 3 content? I already asked Xbox help, and they confirmed it would, but they were not very sure so I am skeptical.

Comment: your asking a few questions here. 1 - can I install RoS and play Diablo, 2 - how much space does both take on console, 3 - why would they take a differant amount of space then pc. Try asking these as separate answers - we do not condone asking multiple questions per question instance. I've edited the question to reflect the primary question, in favor of voting to close the question. If the findings lead you further, ask the other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Diablo 3 RoS on Xbox 360 is a whole new game, it's not Diablo 3 + (RoS as an add-on) (like on PC where RoS is a true add-on). Check on the xbox live you can't buy just RoS as a DLC to play it with your Diablo 3 game.

So Diablo 3 ant Diablo 3 RoS disks are not compatible.

However Blizzard update Diablo 3 on Xbox 360 to allow the transfer of character to the RoS version of the game. Take a look at [this article](http://www.polygon.com/2014/8/6/5976273/blizzard-Diablo-3-save-games).

Comment: Transferring character won't do me any good though. I don't have RoS, and I am not interested in buying it.(plain diablo 3 hasn't been that great, so a expansion that just adds more of the same is eh)  I just want to play the game I do have.

Comment: Are you sure about these games being not compatible? I understand you can't buy the expansion as a separate thing like a PC game, that's typical of how consoles work. But theoretically what the xbox employee said is possible. Have you, or do you know of anyone, or seen anything online about someone installing both diablo 3 plain and RoS on the same xbox? That would be the real test, if installed on the same system, they take up separate spots, then presumably they wouldn't be compatible (I suppose ill have to check) But that you can't buy the expansion by itself does not necessarily mean that.

Comment: Know anything about how much space either of the games take when installed? I am especially interested in first hand experience if you can, do you own either of these games? Though hearsay works for me too.

Comment: I took a look at your link, you missed something big about it. "Here's the fun bit: Moving your save across current-generation consoles won't be supported. Do you own Diablo 3 on the PlayStation 3 and want to bring your character over to the Ultimate Evil Edition on the Xbox 360? No luck. Blizzard is only supporting the export of game saves if you're moving upwards into a next-generation version "  Strangely it doesn't talk about moving it from one version of diablo 3 to another in the same exact system, but presumably not?

It's talking about up to next gen system anyway. It says that clearly

Comment: One thing I am sure is that Diablo 3 RoS on console is not a DLC like all classic Xbox 360 DLC like for example 'The Lost And Dammned' for GTA IV. Like I say in my answer look on the xbox marketplace to buy just RoS as a DLC and you will see that it is not possible. Yes it's not intuitive what blizzard make with this game! You can only buy a game called Diablo 3 reaper of souls that aggregates Diablo 3 + RoS.

Comment: @Truepurple, what do you mean by "Xbox employee"? Also keep in mind that comments are not to be used for discussion. If you want to debate, move it to chat. Marc is completely right on the save file compatibility. The console will not load a Diablo 3 character into Reaper of Souls. On top of that, RoS adds new content. Some of that impacts the character, and as such, the save files are different. Even if the character is missing a tiny bit of data associated with a stable RoS character feature, it would cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

### No, you can not.

**Diablo 3 and Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls are completely different games**, as far as the Xbox 360 is concerned. Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls likely can not actually differentiate between original content and new content, as even the original content has been altered for the expansions release. Here are a few major changes that would be very difficult to naturally interpret by a computer. *Keep in mind that it is not good form to debate the likeliness of interpretation between two consoles, and this only acts as examples of potential issues.*

- **Changes in Difficulty** : In Diablo 3, you can set an overall difficulty. Higher levels of difficulty unlock when you beat Diablo on the previous level of difficulty. In Reaper of Souls, there is no "unlocked difficulty", as the game relies on end-game content, rather then just the replay value of higher levels of difficulty.
- **The Mystic** : Reaper of Sous adds The Mystic, who can add cosmetic changes to items. As Diablo 3 has no implementation of this feature, it would not be able to interpret these cosmetic changes when playing online with other players.
- **New Gear** : There is a bunch of near gear in Reaper of Souls, as well as different methods for determining what gear drops, and how gear changes a character. These changes effect the entire game, not just the last act.

I think there has been confusion between you and Microsoft technical support, in the description of the problem. In most situations, the expansion release is simply the original game, with the expansion provided as completely separate content. In this case, there should be no problem. Your disc validates the original game, and allows you to play the original game. The best way to understand this is that **if you were able to upgrade to Reaper of Souls with a DLC or disc that required the original Diablo 3 to work, you might have luck**.

---

To quote my own interaction with Microsoft technical support, where I spoke to an agent who has experience with Diablo 3,

> **Jason C: at 10:01:53**
> So, that is correct. You cannot use the disc for diablo 3 to access ROS. They are standalone games and that will not let you access the content. If that were the case, they would not have offered the ability to move your characters over to the ROS version. They would have just let it start from where you left off.

---

Marc_Alx has raised a valid point, he simply provided an incorrect source. **You can import your save across to Reaper of Souls, regardless of console generation**. In other words, your Diablo 3 characters can be imported into Reaper of Souls on both Xbox 360 and Xbox One.

[This forum post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14058635813) details the process. While the primary uer appears to have encountered a bug, I can personally vouch for the process. You simply select "Export Save" from the character select screen, in Diablo 3, and from there you should be able to access the character in Reaper of Souls. A forum moderator actually suggests that save transfer is not required on the same console. **Having ran into a slightly similar issue, the best resolution to your primary problem will likely be upgrading to Reaper of Souls, and transfering your character across to the new game.**